# Bluetooth connection getting read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, bluetooth

I am creating an app in Xamarin(Android app), that allows user to send data on his phone via bluetooth connection to another phone. When I click the button it should run the bluetooth getAllPairedDevices and then openConnection, but when it tries to connect it goes into throw exception.

This string sets data variable:

```
       private string data = null;
```

This is my call button, that checks if any devices are paired:

```
        Button btConnect = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.connect);
        btConnect.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            BluetoothManager manager = new BluetoothManager();
            if (manager.getAllPairedDevices() != false)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        data = manager.getDataFromDevice();
                    }
                });
                thread.IsBackground = true;
                thread.Start();
            }
        };
```

And then this is my bluetooth class:

```
public class BluetoothManager
{
    
    // Unique ID for connecting
    private const string UuidUniverseProfile = "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";
    // Incoming bluetooth data from UART
    private BluetoothDevice result;
    // Input/Output stream of this communication
    private BluetoothSocket mSocket;

    // Convert byte[] to strings
    private BufferedReader reader;
    private System.IO.Stream mStream;
    private InputStreamReader mReader;

    public BluetoothManager()
    {
        reader = null;
    }

    private UUID getUUIDfromString()
    {
        return UUID.FromString(UuidUniverseProfile);
    }

    private void close(IDisposable connectedObject)
    {
        if (connectedObject == null) return;
        try
        {
            connectedObject.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        connectedObject = null;
    }

    private void openDeviceConnection(BluetoothDevice btDevice)
    {
        try
        {
            // Getting socket from specific device
            mSocket = btDevice.CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(getUUIDfromString());
            mSocket.Connect();
            // Input stream
            mStream = mSocket.InputStream;
            // Output stream
            //mStream.OutputStream;
            mReader = new InputStreamReader(mStream);
            reader = new BufferedReader(mReader);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            mSocket.Close();
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            close(mSocket);
            close(mStream);
            close(mReader);
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public String getDataFromDevice()
    {
        return reader.ReadLine();
    }

    public bool getAllPairedDevices()
    {
        // Default android phone bluetooth
        BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;
        var devices = btAdapter.BondedDevices;
        if (devices != null && devices.Count > 0)
        {
            // All paired devices
            foreach (BluetoothDevice mDevice in devices)
            {
                openDeviceConnection(mDevice);
            }
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }        
}
```

Since I am new to Bluetooth communication I am not exactly sure where the problem is, I already checked multiple answers, and android.library but it is so complicated, so no luck.

---

Also a subquestion, how would you send a simple string via this setup?